# update state using stream - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

while working on a project, I wanted to update the state using stream.listen() method which didnt work.

**I dont want to use StreamBuilder**
Because it rebuilts the whole ui. and doesnt quite work as expected in sliverlist.

for simplicity I didn't include the appbar and other components that also **Depend on stream values**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage(this.id, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String id;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Subject>? subjects;
  
  initSynced() async {
    final briteDb = await helper.getBriteDatabase();
    final stream = briteDb.createQuery(
             'Subjects',
             where: "subRef = ?",
             whereArgs: [widget.id],
           ).mapToList((e) => Subject.fromDb(e));
    stream.listen((value) {
      print(value); // This runs only once and doesn't refresh;
      setState((){
        subjects = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    initSynced();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(subject == null){
       return Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SubjectCards(
              subjects!,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more about `getStudent`.

Comment: getStudent() is just a function that returns a stream.

Comment: "Because it rebuilts the whole ui" and`setState` is better on that?

Comment: its not like that... I have a sliver list, if i have to use streambuilder on it i have to wrap the customscroll, but rendering everything again is heavy on the user. and i also have 2 streams for one single ui... so if i could update the state it will make things much easier.

Comment: it is not that heavy, it is normal to have for example `StreamBuilder` as a parent of `ListView.builder`

Comment: its a SliverList bro... wrapping SliverChildList with StreamBuilder doesn't work. And also CustomScrollView is already having another StreamBuilder.

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart - `ListView.builder` is nothing but slivers, see line 1171

Comment: I tried with ListView.builder but the SliverAppBar is not hiding while scroll & RefreshIndicator doesnt work too.

Comment: I don't say that you should try ListView.builder - I only say that it uses slivers under the hood but still it works with StreamBuilder as a parent

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I created a gist for dartpad to demonstrate, that stream with listener works for updating the state, when used correctly: https://dartpad.dev/?id=382c51a346d73209a84e2ae514c0b27e

I think the issue with your code lays somewhere with your async code, but as we can't see your implementation of getStudent I can only guess.

You should play around with your code a bit more to figure out if the stream is actually initialized or not (does it print the values when they are received?) and as an advice I really recommend learning State Management libraries, such as Provider, BloC, RiverPod or others, as they allow you to granually control your UI from anywhere in the app. For example it can allow you to update only the parts of UI that changed the value. You can find out more information in official documentations of these packages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Riverpod for state management in Flutter
https://riverpod.dev/

You can use the FutureProvider, for example if you have to read data from your database (or any other async operation):

```
final configProvider = FutureProvider<List<Subject>>((ref) async {
final briteDb = await helper.getBriteDatabase();
return await briteDb.createQuery(
         'Subjects',
         where: "subRef = ?",
         whereArgs: [widget.id],
       ).mapToList((e) => Subject.fromDb(e));
});
```

Now, use it in a StatefulWidget as follows ( using Riverpod , we should use ConsumerStatefuleWidget and not the StatefulWidget ) :

```
class MyHomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
    const MyHomePage(this.id, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);    
    final String id;
      @override
      ConsumerState<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {
     

      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AsyncValue<List<Subject>> data= ref.watch(configProvider);
    return config.when(
            loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
             error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
            data: (subjects) {
           return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SubjectCards(
              subjects!,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4
        ),
      ),
    );
           },
    );
    
  }
}
```